# Confusion regarding substitution of $\overline{x}$ for $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

A Cauchy sequence $\langle x\rangle$ is defined as such: for any $\epsilon\in\Bbb{R}$, there is an $m\in\Bbb{N}$ such that for any $k,l\geq m$, $|x_{k}-x_{l}|<\epsilon$.

I refer to the proof given on pg. 4 of [this](http://econ.la.psu.edu/~hbierens/HILBERT.PDF) article.

It says *keeping $k$ fixed and letting $m\to\infty$, it follows that $|x_{n_{k}}-\overline{x}|<\epsilon$*. 
$\overline{x}=\limsup_{n\to\infty}x_{n}$.

**Is the substitution of $\overline{x}$ for $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{n}$ valid?**

In my opinion, this treats $\infty$ like an integer.

Comment: It in no way treats $\infty$ as an integer. There is a small technical error, however: the correct conclusion from letting $m\to\infty$ with $k$ held fixed is that $|x_{n_k}-\bar x|\le\epsilon$, with a non-strict inequality. This is simply the fact that if $y_n\to y$, and $|y_n|<z$ for all $n$, then $|y|\le z$.

Comment: Brian, how about this? Let $lim_{n\to\infty}x_{n}=\overline{x}$. For any $\epsilon\in\Bbb{R}$, for some $k,l>N$, $|x_{k}-x_{l}|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Also, there is an $M\in\Bbb{N}$ such that for any $c>M$, $|x_{c}-\overline{x}|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Let $l>max(M,N)$. Then $|x_{k}-\overline{x}|=|x_{k}-x_{l}+x_{l}-\overline{x}|\leq |x_{k}-x_{l}|+|x_{l}-\overline{x}|=\epsilon$. Woudn't this be a more systematic way of proving it than just substituting $x_{m},m\to\infty$ for $\overline{x}$?

Comment: What you’ve done doesn’t work: the argument at this point is proving that $\bar x$ is finite, something that you’re simply assuming. In any case that argument in the PDF (and in more general form in my previous comment) is a very standard one that you need to understand.

Comment: Your insistence on inserting the undefined and (a priori) possibly nonexisting quantity $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n$ in a reasoning using the always defined and always existing quantity $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n$ suggests that you might fail to realize the difference between them. Do you know how $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n$ is defined?

Comment: @Did- I did considerabe reading post this question on the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem, and now do understand the argument. I suppose $lim_{n\to\infty}sup x_{n}$ is the supremum of the monotone subsequence of the sequence $\langle x_{n}\rangle$, which also turns out to be the limit of $\langle x_{n}\rangle$ provided it is convergent.

Comment: "the supremum of the monotone subsequence of the sequence" is dangerously imprecise. My advice is to CHECK THE DEFINITION of limsup before going any further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As Brian M. Scott noticed, the argument is correct, except that that $|x_{n_k}−\bar x|< \epsilon$ should be replaced with $|x_{n_k}−\bar x|\le \epsilon$. Passing to the limit in an inequality preserve non-strict inequalities, but need not preserve strict ones.
2. The proof could be simplified (and made more clear) by isolating a part of it:

> Every Cauchy sequence is bounded.

Indeed, there is $N$ such that $|x_m-x_n|\le 1$ whenever $m,n\ge N$. Then let $$r=\max(|x_k-x_N| : 1\le k<N)+1$$ and observe that $|x_n-x_N|\le r$ for all $n$. $\quad \Box$

Now the proof simplifies because we already know that $\bar x$ is finite, without that limiting argument. We don't even need to bring the $\liminf$ into the game: having $x_{n_k}\to \bar x$ is enough because [Cauchy sequence is convergent iff it has a convergent subsequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/354965/85506).