# Why don't all sequences on compact metric spaces converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

My thinking is this: Let $(X, d)$ be a compact metric space, thus it is also sequentially compact, meaning that all sequences have a convergent subsequence. We also know that [every compact metric space is complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_metric_space#Some_theorems).

Now we also know that [a sequence is Cauchy iff it has a convergent subsequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/354965/cauchy-sequence-is-convergent-iff-it-has-a-convergent-subsequence), but since our space is complete, they should converge?

Example: Let $X = [0, 1] \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $d$ some metric. By Heine-Borel's theorem, $X$ is compact, since it is closed and bounded. Now, looking at the alternating sequence $(x_n)_{n = 0}^{\infty}$ given by:

$$
x_n = \begin{cases}
0, & \text{$n$ is even} \\
1, & \text{$n$ is odd}
\end{cases}
$$

This sequence obviously doesn't converge. Where am I going wrong in this? Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you take every other term of your sequence, you have a convergent subsequence.

Comment: It is not true that any sequence with a convergent subsequence is Cauchy. Read that linked question a little more carefully.

Comment: The result in the linked question is that a sequence that we already know is Cauchy converges if and only if it has a convergent subsequence. If we only know that a sequence has a convergent subsequence, there is no reason to expect that it is Cauchy. In fact, since the space is compact this describes any sequence, convergent or not.

Comment: Ah, thanks guys! That makes sense.